# How to create feature toggling when spring security is enabled on ff4j?

Tags: spring-security, ff4j

I did the following steps and I don't understand why I did not succeed on the last one :

1. clone this [repository](https://github.com/ff4j/ff4j-samples/tree/master/spring-boot-2x/ff4j-sample-security-spring)
2. start spring boot app
3. browse to http://localhost:5002/ff4j-web-console/features
4. login with `user/user` (also tried `admin/admin` and `superuser/superuser`)
5. try to create new feature but got a 403 error message

I want to have the console (+api) protected by a basic authentication but I want to be able to do anything when I'm logged. How can I achieve this ? Am I missing something on how security works between spring and ff4j ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Spring Security with Java configuration, CSRF protection is enabled by default. In this context, if you make an Ajax request to a REST endpoint using POST method, you will get a csrf token missing error.

To fix it, in class `SecurityConfig` change`configure` method with the following. The code has been updated in github as well.

```java
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
 http.csrf().disable()
     .authorizeRequests()
     .anyRequest().authenticated()
     .and().formLogin();
}
```